# exhaustive search matlab 4 variables

Tags: matlab, optimization, brute-force

I used genetic algorithm to find the minimum of a **4** variable(x1,x2,x3,x4) objective function(output result1). Now, to evaluate the results i need to run an exhaustive search in the following manner:I will keep x1,x2 constant and x3 x4 will take n values between their upper and lower bounds with a fixed step.I will need to store the results to different vectors to see the combination of x1,x2,x3,x4 that minimizes result1(the output of the objective function). X1,x2,x3,x4 have also linear and non linear contraints which are implemented in the genetic algorithm. Any ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are stuck on a basic level.

Try looping over all values of x3 and x4 that you want to check and evaluate the value in each point. Keep track of he best value and the location where you found it, and update this each time you find a better one.

If this works, you can start thinking about efficiency (vectorization, gradient search).